# ASP.NET 2.0 application won't compile when adding a Microsoft Report to the solution

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, .net-2.0

I have a ASP.NET 2.0 web application. To that solution I add a Report (Reporting Services).

I make no further changes to that report. When I try build the application the build fails with the following error originating from that report file:

> A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or
>   methods

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Visual Studio. I've restarted the IDE and could compile the application without problems.